# Unit testing with legacy library

Tags: c#, unit-testing, oop

I`m developing a C# small app which consumes data from a legacy library and I was wondering the best way to unit test. The legacy library is essentially a function which is connected with a remote server and returns a big object that I have to process in my app.

My first thought was to create three classes:

- A: for store the object properties I'm interested in
- B: for isolate the legacy function (just one method which returns an instance of A)
- C: My "real" app (Calls B method and process the A instance)

So, in order to test my app the natural way seems to create a mock which implements the B interface and returns an instance of A with the right properties for each test but... I realized that 90% of code I wrote is on A and B (function call, error handling, A instance creation and filling,...) instead of C (the class I was designing to be testable) and, more than that, the code which is really important to test was in B.

To fix this, I decided to move as much code as possible to C, but even with that, 70% of code was still in A and B (A has a lot of properties to be filled when created).

So, I tried to remove A and return the whole object that legacy function returns but, sadly, this object can not be instantiated, so it can not be created in mock implementation of B.

Finally, I decided to implement a (unit?) test which calls the B method in order to validate the B implementation but, obviously, B is consuming data from a remote server which is not always available (it will not work in my CI build server...)

Is there any better approach for this? Any way of isolate the function of the rest of the code I wrote?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should never have to unit test 3rd party code. Just as you trust that the SQL Server adapter for .NET works as intended, you don't need to make your own units tests for that. I would split your app into two abstractions: one that fetches the large object and one that performs the actual processing. This would allow you to test those two parts individually (as is suitable when it comes to unit testing).

Comment: thank you for your answer @silkfire. What I´m trying to test is the small portion of code which is adapting the legacy function to be "testable". Is small since is not much code but, even so, it's the 70% of the code I have to create and the more error prone one (mainly property assignments which can easily fail due to casting issues). I can not see clearly how to apply your approach to cover this assignments. Could you please elaborate it a bit more? Thanks